# In C++, I want two classes to access each other

Tags: c++

I have two classes, `class A` and `class B`.

```
A.h -> A.cpp
B.h -> B.cpp
```

And then, I set B as a member in class A. Then, class A can access class B by

```
#include <B.h>
```

But, how can I get the pointer of class A in class B and access the public member of class A?

I found some information about on the internet: a Cross-class. They said you can make it by setting the class B as a nested class in class A.

Do you have any other advice?

sorry.
myCode: as follow..

```
class A:

#ifndef A
#define A

#include "B.h"

class A
{
public:
    A() {
        b = new B(this);
    }

private:
    B* b;
};

#endif


#ifndef B
#define B

#include"A.h"

class B
{
public:
    B(A* parent = 0) {
        this->parent = parent;
    }

private:
    A* parent;
};

#endif
```

Comment: what are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: Please post some relevant code.

Comment: The second time it should read as `class B`, not `A`, right? Otherwise it's a redefinition anyway, i.e. an error.

Comment: Sorry..   just a moment ago, My code is chaos . Now it is clear.. Thank you ..

Comment: doing this `#define A` is going to cause problems (especially since you have a classed called `A`). Try and make your Macros unique.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use [forward declaration](http://www-subatech.in2p3.fr/~photons/subatech/soft/carnac/CPP-INC-1.shtml). Like:

A.h:

```
#ifndef A_h
#define A_h

class B; // B forward-declaration

class A // A definition
{
public:
    B * pb; // legal, we don't need B's definition to declare a pointer to B 
    B b;    // illegal! B is an incomplete type here
    void method();
};

#endif
```

B.h:

```
#ifndef B_h
#define B_h

#include "A.h" // including definition of A

class B // definition of B
{
public:
    A * pa; // legal, pointer is always a pointer
    A a;    // legal too, since we've included A's *definition* already
    void method();
};

#endif
```

A.cpp

```
#inlude "A.h"
#incude "B.h"

A::method()
{
    pb->method(); // we've included the definition of B already,
                  // and now we can access its members via the pointer.
}
```

B.cpp

```
#inlude "A.h"
#incude "B.h"

B::method()
{
    pa->method(); // we've included the definition of A already
    a.method();   // ...or like this, if we want B to own an instance of A,
                  // rather than just refer to it by a pointer.
}
```

Knowing that `B is a class` is enough for compiler to define `pointer to B`, whatever `B` is. Of course, both `.cpp` files should include `A.h` and `B.h` to be able to access class members.

Comment: thank you ..   But if i will access class B in class A ?  how can i do ?

Comment: In `.cpp` files you can then include both headers and access both classes' members, and in headers you generally shouldn't access them at all.

Comment: if i must do it, i can make class B as a nested-class in class A ? ..and i make it...  But i make a project that : there is a mainWindow operator and lots of member-object like this, I will access member-object in mainWindow, and get the pointer of mainWindow in member-object and access mainWindow public function.. I think it is very Cumbersome... Do you hava a way to make it ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand.. But there's no need for netsing here.

Comment: Ah, now it's clearer. Looks like you have to forward-declare MainWindow class in members' header files.

Comment: i.e.    like this :  in A.h : #include<B.h>    and in B.h : #include<A.h>  .. right ?

Comment: Tank you very much ...  Master.